# Expected Return, Expected Value, and an Ito Process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, expectation, brownian-motion, economics

I am reading John Hull's "Options, Futures, and Other Derivatives". I am currently in Ch. 31 on the HJM Model.  Hull makes a statement which a need an explanation for.  First, some notation.  Let $P(t,T)$ be the price at time $t$ of a zero-coupon bond with principal $\$1$ maturing at time $T$. Let $r(t)$ be the short term risk free interest rate at time.  dz(t) is a Wiener process a.k.a z(t) is a Brownian motion. And $v(t,T,\Omega_t)$ is the volatity based on $t$, $T$, and $\Omega_t$ which a vector of pertinent information. Now here is the statement I need an explanation for:

"We use the risk-neutral world.  A zero-coupon bond is a traded security providing no income. Its return in the risk-neutral world must therefore be $r$.  This means its stochastic process has the form $dP(t,T)=r(t)P(t,T)dt+v(t,T,\Omega_t)P(t,T)dz(t)$."

I don't understand how we get that stochastic process.  If $r$ was constant as was the volaltilty, then we would have Geometric Brownian Motion and I would follow the result for the Expected value I think.  But since $r$ and $v$ are not constant, I am lost.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: What's the problem...? In a deterministic world, do you agree that the return $\frac{dP_t}{P_t} = r_t dt$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the risk neutral world, assets discounted at the risk free rate are martingales - that means they are neither expected to increase or decrease in value over a time horizon. This is only possible if it drifts according to $r(t)P(t,T)dt$. To see what this means, take the expectation of the present value of the bond at time $t$, and you will find it's expectation to be just $P(0,T)$.

$$
\begin{align*}
d\left(e^{-\int_0^t r(t) dt} P(t,T)\right) &= e^{-\int_0^t r(t) dt} dP(t,T) + P(t,T)d\left(e^{-\int_0^t r(t) dt}\right) \\
&= e^{-\int_0^t r(t) dt} r(t)P(t,T) dt + e^{-\int_0^t r(t) dt}v(t,T,\Omega_t)P(t,T) dz(t) - e^{-\int_0^t r(t) dt}r(t)P(t,T)dt \\
&= e^{-\int_0^t r(t) dt}v(t,T,\Omega_t)P(t,T) dz(t) \\
\Longrightarrow e^{-\int_0^t r(t) dt}P(t,T) &= P(0,T)+ \int_0^t e^{-\int_0^s r(u) du}v(s,T,\Omega_s)P(s,T) dz(s)
\end{align*}
$$

Taking expectations shows that in fact the discounted value of the bond at time $t$ is exactly the same as its value at time 0. viz.,

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[e^{-\int_0^t r(t) dt}P(t,T)\right]=P(0,T)
$$